# getting InflateException when Clicking on Pay Button Payfort PaymentGateway android SDK < Error inflating class com.shamanland.fonticon.FontIconView >

Tags: android, payfort

I am integrating `Payfort Payment gateway` android sdk in my app, every thing is working fine till Payment on Last screen using sdk. 
When Clicking on PAY button on the XML design provided by Payfort Team then I am getting

```
{
        if (isInEditMode()) {
            mOldValuesSaver = null;
        } else {
            setTypeface(FontIconTypefaceHolder.getTypeface());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                mOldValuesSaver = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        saveOldValues();
                    }
                };
            } else {
                mOldValuesSaver = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        saveOldValuesJB();
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

In above method,the line(setTypeface(FontIconTypefaceHolder.getTypeface());) is throwing the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.payfort.payfort/com.example.payfort.payfort.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.shamanland.fonticon.FontIconView
```

Any Help would be appreciated.
Please find the Logs below

> /com.example.payfort.payfort E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.payfort.payfort, PID: 23352
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.payfort.payfort/com.example.payfort.payfort.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error
>   inflating class com.shamanland.fonticon.FontIconView at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) Caused
>   by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error
>   inflating class com.shamanland.fonticon.FontIconView at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>   at
>   com.example.payfort.payfort.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) Caused
>   by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>   at
>   com.example.payfort.payfort.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) Caused
>   by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at
>   com.shamanland.fonticon.FontIconTypefaceHolder.getTypeface(FontIconTypefaceHolder.java:13)
>   at com.shamanland.fonticon.FontIconView.(FontIconView.java:129)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>   at
>   com.example.payfort.payfort.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: Getting Same Error!

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
FontIconTypefaceHolder.init(getAssets(), "icons.ttf");
```

before setcontentview